# Probability for sold items

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

A salesperson has a probability of 70% to make a sale.

Answer (score 1):

The way to answer this is to use the Normal approximation to the binomial distribution. The number of sales is assumed to be distributed as $ X \sim Bin (500,0.7) $. The take home pay is $ Y = 50 + 10X $, which you can rearrange to $ X=\frac{Y-50}{10} $. You want to find the probability that $ Y> y $ (when $ y=4800$), so work out what that means in terms of the value of $ X $. Then compute the Normal approximation of $ X $, $ X^\prime \sim N (\mu,\sigma^2) $ and then calculate $\Pr(X^\prime > x) $ where $ x $ is the value of $ X $ for which $ Y=4800$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are interested in is the variance of the binomial distribution. Consider that you are essentially counting up a series of successes and failures (a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials). Since this is self study, I won't explicitly give the answer.

Note: @tristan isn't wrong. However, with computers around, you can get a more accurate answer by using the true distribution (Binomial) than with a Normal approximation.

Comment: Agreed, I had assumed given what was posted that a Normal approximation was the desired approach. Also in a pen and paper exam with a pocket calculator the Normal approximations are very handy!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the salesperson sees 3 customers a day with 70% chance of a sale for each.

- Probability of 0 sales = 0.027
- Probability of 1 or more sales = 0.973
- Probability of 2 or more sales = 0.784
- Probability of 3 sales = 0.343

Based on this, expand to 500 customers a day. It helps to use the binomial distribution function.

Comment: Thank you for this simple example. But I am not sure how to incorporate the \$4800 here? In my question in order to have \$4800 and above the salesperson will need to make at least 475 sales (4800-50)/10. If I use Binomial(500,0.7) and ask for the right side of 475, my software gives me a very small value as 475 is way to the right.

Comment: For >= 475 the value is indeed very small. http://vassarstats.net/binomialX.html says <0.000000000001